# how to parse a serialized array to a jQuery array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, parsing, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a jQuery sortable list and I am serializing the result.

```
var data = $("#sortable").sortable('serialize');
```

The result looks like this:

```
item[]=41&item[]=49&item[]=51&item[]=35&item[]=58&item[]=45&item[]=32&item[]=36&item[]=26&item[]=27&item[]=33&item[]=31&item[]=29
```

Now I want to select each array index by using jQuery `$each`.

```
    $.each(data, function(index,  value ) {

        alert( value );
    });
```

And I will get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in item[]=51&item[]=41&item[]=49&item[]=35&item[]=58&item[]=45&item[]=32&item[]=36&item[]=26&item[]=27&item[]=33&item[]=31&item[]=29

So probably I have to parse it to an array using JSON.parse():

```
        var data = $("#sortable").sortable('serialize');
    data=JSON.parse(data);
    $.each(data, function(index,  value ) {
        alert( value );
    });
```

That will causes the error

> VM327:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 0

So it might be the problem that JSON parser expects a string with `"` at the beginning and the ending.

```
var data = $("#sortable").sortable('serialize');
    data=JSON.stringify(data);
    data=JSON.parse(data);
    $.each(data, function(index,  value ) {
        alert( value );
    });
```

But this will lead to the first TypeError.

How can I parse a jQuery sortable object to a data array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "toArray" method instead of the "serialize" method.

```
var arr = $("#sortable").sortable('toArray');
$.each(arr, function(index, value) {
    alert(value);
});
```

---

BTW, a String of the following form is not JSON. In fact, it is not even close to JSON.

> item[]=51&item[]=41&item[]=49&item[]=35&item[]=58&item[]=45&item[]=32&item[]=36&item[]=26&item[]=27&item[]=33&item[]=31&item[]=29

A JSON string for an array would look like:

> [51, 41, 49, 35, 58, 45, 32, 36, 26, 27, 33, 31, 29]